# can't start prestodb server over https with a custom password authenticator

Tags: presto

I'm using presto 0.206 and trying to config it to run over https with a password authenticator that i wrote.

I get the following error -

```
2018-10-29T16:24:45.974+0200    INFO    main    com.facebook.presto.server.security.PasswordAuthenticatorManager    -- Loading password authenticator --
2018-10-29T16:24:45.976+0200    INFO    main    Bootstrap   PROPERTY  DEFAULT  RUNTIME  DESCRIPTION
2018-10-29T16:24:45.980+0200    INFO    main    com.facebook.presto.server.security.PasswordAuthenticatorManager    -- Loaded password authenticator v3io --
2018-10-29T16:24:45.989+0200    INFO    main    com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer ======== SERVER STARTED ========
2018-10-29T16:24:45.989+0200    ERROR   Announcer-0 io.airlift.discovery.client.Announcer   Cannot connect to discovery server for announce: Announcement failed for https://192.168.224.157:8889
2018-10-29T16:24:45.990+0200    ERROR   Announcer-0 io.airlift.discovery.client.Announcer   Service announcement failed after 9.44ms. Next request will happen within 0.00s
```

looks like my plugin ("v3io") is loaded successfully but something is wrong with the https config

**config.properties -**

```
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.https.enabled=true
http-server.https.port=8889
query.max-memory=5GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=https://192.168.224.157:8889
node.internal-address=192.168.224.157
http-server.https.keystore.path=/opt/presto-server-0.206/keystore.jks
http-server.https.keystore.key=password
http-server.authentication.type=PASSWORD
```

Comment: In case anyone else is trying to make a password authenticator, I made a blog here: https://coding-stream-of-consciousness.com/2019/06/18/presto-custom-password-authentication-plugin-internal/ with the rough process.  I read this and about 40 other posts before I got mine working (even though it's fairly straight forward in the end).  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `discovery.uri` value to be `http` not `https`. I don’t think it supports HTTPS.

Comment: It has to be https otherwise the cli won't allow inserting user and password - 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Authentication using username/password requires HTTPS to be enabled
 at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:135)
 at com.facebook.presto.cli.QueryRunner.setupBasicAuth(QueryRunner.java:146)
 at com.facebook.presto.cli.QueryRunner.<init>(QueryRunner.java:79)
 at com.facebook.presto.cli.Console.run(Console.java:138)
 at com.facebook.presto.cli.Presto.main(Presto.java:31)

Comment: coming back the update that the above answer is correct. my confusion was that i thought discovery.uri should be the same as --server property passed to cli. 
discovery can be http while --server can be https